# How to compare values from a google sheets column to an array and send to specific emails based on column data and send emails to specific users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm automating my google sheets to send out emails automatically and I can't figure out how to compare a variable array to a column in my google sheets. I keep getting all values returned rather than just the ones in my array when I put it in an 'IF' statement.
I want my code to only show data that is in my gEnglish variable but instead shows me all data. I was also wondering how I'd be able to send emails based on regions to users.

```js
function sendEmails() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main").activate();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  
  var decisionOne = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var decisionTWO = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var decisionThree = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(3,1).getValue();
  var decisionFour = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(5,1).getValue();
  var decisionFive = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(4,1).getValue();
  
  var gEnglish = ["IT","US","GB","UK"];
  var gSpanish = ["SP"];
  
  var user1 = ["JP","SK","IND","RU"];
  var user2 = [gEnglish,"UK"];
  var user3 = [gSpanish, "BR", "PT"];
  var user4 = ["FR", "DE","IT"];
  
  for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){
    var type = ss.getRange(i,6).getValue();
    var region = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var decision = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();
    //I used to have if(region == gEnglish)
    if(gEnglish.includes(region[i]) ){
      var channel = ss.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      var decision = ss.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      var url = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
      var name = ss.getRange(i,11).getValue();
      var messageBody = {};
      var subjectLine = "blahblahblah";
    }    
  }
}
```

If my array only has one value inside it works fine but as soon as I put more I just get all values returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*`.getValue()` returns the data of the cell, not an array. You do not therefore need to reference the data with `region[i]`.*

#### More Information:

Say you have the value "Hello World" in cell `C1`. To get this value, you have the `getValue()` and `getValues()` methods of the `Range` object.

If you run the following code:

```
let c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                      .getRange("C1");

console.log(c.getValue());
console.log(c.getValues());
```

The execution log will display the following:

```
Oct 26, 2020, 11:42:39 AM   Debug   Hello World
Oct 26, 2020, 11:42:39 AM   Debug   [ 'Hello World' ]
```

Doing the same, but accessing element[0]:

```
let c = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                      .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                      .getRange("C1");

console.log(c.getValue()[0]);
console.log(c.getValues()[0]);
```

Will display the following inthe execution log:

```
Oct 26, 2020, 11:44:39 AM   Debug   H
Oct 26, 2020, 11:44:39 AM   Debug   Hello World
```

#### Fix:

Change the following line:

```
if (gEnglish.includes(region[i])) {
  //...
}
```

to:

```
if (gEnglish.includes(region)) {
  // ...
}
```

#### References:

- [Class Range - `getValue()` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [Class Range - `getValues()` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was extremely helpful and fixed one of my major problems! Was wondering if I also had to put a for loop before var =user that contains my array since it doesn't iterate very well? e.g var user2 = [gEnglish, "UK"]; doesn't work since I have gEnglish inside of it

Comment: Glad to help! I'm not 100% sure what you mean but if you're trying to set `var user2 = ["IT","US","GB","UK","UK]` you can do `var user2 = [gEnglish,"UK"].flat()`.